# scaling data-frame with numeric and categorical

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

i am in python, i have data-frame that contain both numeric  as in the following

```sql
     subject_id  |   pH       |  urinecolor |  blood pressure  
     --------------------------------------------------------                
        3        |  1.00      |  red        |  high
        3        |  1.15      |  red        |  high
        4        |  2.00      |  yellow     |  low
```

and categorical . i want to scale and normalize data frame but the traditional scaling give error cant scale string 
i try the following, but it give me the return as list , i want to scale columns and return the whole dataframe for further steps , any one help me in that. thanks in advance

```py
    df= pd.readcsv()
    dfTest =df.select_dtypes(include='number')
    scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)
    dftest= df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
    X = scaler.fit_transform(dftest)
```

Comment: Some data would help to see what you are doing and what is going on.

Comment: Also, you can do the normalization yourself.  Find the mean, df['col1'].mean() and find the standard deviation, df['col1'].std().  Your normalized data would be df['norm_col1']= (df['col1']-df['col1'].mean())/df['col1'].std()

Comment: i am edit it with sample dataset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scaling/Normalization would only work with numeric columns. For categorical columns, there are other techniques available such as [`label encoding`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), [`one hot encoding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) etc. Here's what you can do:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()

# get numeric data
num_d = d.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])

# update the cols with their normalized values
d[num_d.columns] = sc.fit_transform(num_d)

# convert string variable to One Hot Encoding
d = pd.get_dummies(d)

   subject_id        pH  urinecolor_red  urinecolor_yellow
0   -0.707107 -0.870563               1                  0
1   -0.707107 -0.529908               1                  0
2    1.414214  1.400471               0                  1
```

Hope this gives you some idea.